# Как выборочно запустить junit тесты которые имеют несколько аннотаций

Tags: java, junit, аннотации

Есть 200 тест кейсов. В разных классах, в каждом из них есть по несколько методов, у которых по несколько аннотаций, допустим: `@RUS` `@USA` `@CAN` `@WORK` `@STUDY` `@TRAVEL`.

Какие-то содержат все аннотации, а некоторые частично, а некоторые вообще только пару.

Как запустить только те методы которые удовлетворяют только требованию, скажем: `@USA` `@STUDY`, и игнорирует те в которых их нет?

Answer (score 1):

Варианта два:

1. Написать свой `org.junit.runner.Runner`, который будет проверять через рефлексию аннотации на тестах и запускать только нужные по вашему фильтру.
2. Отказаться от аннотаций в пользу существующего механизма [Categories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Categories), который в принципе уже решает вашу задачу: каждый тест может быть отнесен к одной или нескольким категориям, при прогоне можно выбирать включаемые и исключаемые категории. Для вашего примера будет выглядеть как-то так:

   ```
   public interface Rus {}
   public interface Usa {}
   public interface Work {}
   public interface Study {}


   public class SomeTests {
     @Test @Category(Rus.class)
     public void testFoo() { ... }

     @Test @Category(Usa.class)
     public void testBar() { ... } 

     @Test @Category(Study.class)
     public void testBaz() { ... } 
   }

   @RunWith(Categories.class)
   @IncludeCategory({ Usa.class, Study.class })
   @SuiteClasses({ SomeTests.class })
   public UsaStudyTestSuite {}
   ```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Но скорее всего подойдет первый вариант больше, так как нельзя отказаться от аннотаций. Буду искать подробнее. Если же можете, опишите подробнее первый вариант?

Answer (score 1):

немного кастомный метод, но работает.

```
public class TestTemplate extends BaseTest{

    @Category(DefaultCategory.CategoryA.class)
    @Test
    public void testA(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }


    @Category(DefaultCategory.CategoryB.class)
    @Test
    public void testB1(){
        System.out.println("B1");
    }

    @Category(DefaultCategory.CategoryB.class)
    @Test
    public void testB(){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

дальше идет описание базового класса, где определяется какие методы нужно выполнить. Вы сами можете создать свои категории Rus, Usa, Study по подобию CategoryA и CategoryB

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;
import org.junit.rules.TestName;
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.util.HashSet;

@Slf4j
public class BaseTest {
    public static String caseCategories;
    public static String[] currentCaseCategories = null;
    public static HashSet<String> ignoringCategories = new HashSet<>();

    static {
        System.setProperty("test.category.for.exec", "CategoryB");
    }

    @Rule
    public TestName name = new TestName();

    @Before
    public void beforeMethod() {
        currentCaseCategories = getCategories();
        if (currentCaseCategories != null)
            for (String category : currentCaseCategories) {
                if (!category.contains(System.getProperty("test.category.for.exec")))
                    ignoringCategories.add(category);
            }
        boolean isCurrentCatIgnore = isContains(ignoringCategories, currentCaseCategories);

        org.junit.Assume.assumeFalse("Ignore next test cases", isCurrentCatIgnore);
        log.info("###################################################################");
        log.info(name.getMethodName());
        log.info(System.lineSeparator());
        currentCaseCategories = null;
    }

    /**
     * Нам нужно создать категории, которые будем вешать на тестовый метод.
     */
    public static class DefaultCategory {
        public static class CategoryA implements Category {

            @Override
            public Class<?>[] value() {
                return new Class<?>[0];
            }

            /**
             * Returns the annotation type of this annotation.
             *
             * @return the annotation type of this annotation
             */
            @Override
            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static class CategoryB implements Category {

            @Override
            public Class<?>[] value() {
                return new Class<?>[0];
            }

            /**
             * Returns the annotation type of this annotation.
             *
             * @return the annotation type of this annotation
             */
            @Override
            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает текущие категории
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String[] getCategories() {
        String cases = null;
        String[] caseArr = null;
        if (this.caseCategories == null) return null;

        // удаляем все лишнеи пути до класса с категориями
        cases = this.caseCategories.substring(51, this.caseCategories.length() - 2);
        cases = cases.replace("class ", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        caseArr = cases.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < caseArr.length; i++) {
            caseArr[i] = caseArr[i].replace("$", ".");
        }
        return caseArr;

    }

    @Rule
    public TestRule watchman = new TestWatcher() {
        // этот ментод выполняется до выполнения метода @Test
        @Override
        protected void starting(Description description) {
            super.starting(description);
            caseCategories = null;
            for (Annotation annotation : description.getAnnotations()) {
                String d = annotation.toString();
                if (d.startsWith("@org.junit.experimental.categories.Category")) {
                    // запоминаем все аннотации
                    caseCategories = d;
                }
            }
        }

    };

    private boolean isContains(HashSet<String> hashSet, String[] categories) {
        if (categories != null)
            for (String s : categories) {
                if (hashSet.contains(s)) return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

}
```

в таком случае, тест testA() будет игнорен точно также, как с аннотацией @Ignore